# Facebook SDK get albums and photos not working

Tags: php, facebook

So, right know it returns the data for the albums..album names,but I also need that cover image for the album, and the photos for each album, here is my current code:

```
function get_albums($facebook)
{
    $fb_user = $this->getFbUser($facebook);
    $myalbums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
    return $myalbums["data"];
}

function getFbUser($facebook)
{
    $fb_user = $facebook->getUser(); //gets user id

    if(is_null($fb_user))
    {
            header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'))}");
            exit;
    }
    return $fb_user;
}

function getFb()
{
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'secret',
        'secret' => 'secret',
        'cookie' => true,
        ));
    return $facebook;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
/*
   $albID pass the album ID
*/
function get_fbimages($facebook,$albID = null)
{
$fb_user = $this->getFbUser($facebook);
$myimages = $facebook->api("/$albID/photos");
return $myimages;
}
```